# Is the phrase "doing something led by an interest (in)" correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is it semantically correct to say that someone is doing something *led by an interest* of some kind? For example:

> I am calling you led by an interest in your declaration.

PS I've definitely heard the above phrase in informal conversation, however, I'm not sure whether it is formally acceptable.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you heard that construction in informal conversations among *native* speakers.  I wouldn't phrase anything that way (the problem isn't "led by an interest", so much, because that's workable, it's using it after "I'm calling you", in that way).

Comment: What is "STH" in your title?

Comment: Well, it was not exactly a conversation in the usual sense of the word. A foreign classmate of mine asked me way back whether the referred phrase is correct, and back then I was convinced it does not sound right. However, just a few minute ago another foreign classmate asked me the same, and I've started doubting...

Comment: @ TrevorD: Abbreviation for *SomeTHing*

Comment: Please try not to use text-message abbreviations. Not everybody knows them, and we try to make our questions and answers understandable by the general reader.

Comment: @DJClayworth In this case, it's not a text-message abbreviation, it's a consequence of studying English formally, where dictionaries and other resources (textbooks, grammars) use these frequently (*sb* = *somebody* etc).

Answer (score 0):

British English native speaker. Never heard of it. You may have heard it somewhere, but I suggest you do not imitate it.